# parse_qsl error django

Tags: python, django

In the file: django/http/**init**.py line: 341

```
for key, value in parse_qsl((query_string or ''), True): # keep_blank_values=True
```

query_string = 'rtp_last_name=Mart%EDnez&x_first_name=Cu%F1al%F3'

but when parse_qsl is executed the result is

[('rtp_last_name', 'Mart\xednez'), ('x_first_name', 'Cu\xf1al\xf3')]

So, when I put these values on a django.form the words are Mart�nez and Cu�al�.

The original values are Martínes and Cuñaló, but parse_qsl convert **%ED** to **\xed**, but the correct convertion is **%ED** to **í**

Any hint?

PD: this happen when authorize.net answers the transaction via POST.

Comment: So... you want to override the *correct* handling and do something else?

Comment: I'm running into a similar error. So strange. When Django runs through WSGI, 'players=4&include=pa%C2%B0l%C2%B0' gets converted into [('players', '4'), ('include', 'pa\\xc2\\xb0l\\xc2\\xb0')]], but when run through shell, [('players', '4'), ('include', 'pa\xc2\xb0l\xc2\xb0')]. No clue yet where these double-slashes are coming from.